# how to custom intent to ask for permisson in mediaProjection in android?

Tags: android

If I want to create mediaProjection I have to use `createScreenCaptureIntent` to ask the permission right?

then on ActivityResult I can get the mediaProjection by result code and data.

Can I create my own intent and Activity to ask user if he want to start record screen? or mirror screen?

I tried but it will return null in getMediaProjection even if I put extra.

```
myIntent.putExtra("android.media.projection.extra.EXTRA_MEDIA_PROJECTION",myInetnt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly. But if you want to ask for permission for screen recording, this would be the right way (as of API 30):

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
  new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
  new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
      if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
        // your code, e.g. start a new activity
      } else {
        // no permission given, finish your app
      }
    }
  }
);

MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent());
launcher.launch(myIntent);
```

Comment: (mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent() will use the system alert dialog to ask permission which can not custom right? can I use my own Intent?

Comment: So you want to have your own dialog to ask for the permission?

Comment: yes @Cloverleaf

Comment: If custom dialogs were possible, we would have a serious security problem: you could ask the user something that he will answer "yes" to, and thus 
get his permission to film his screen (e.g. entering passwords) without him knowing it. I am pretty sure that this is not possible.

Comment: then only custom the dialog style (background color or others) not change the words?

Comment: and I only want to share the screen why I need the intent of capture?createScreenCaptureIntent

Comment: `only custom the dialog style, not change the words?`  - Never seen or heard about ...

Comment: `and I ONLY want to` - Sharing your screen is **very serious**: if you share your screen with me, I can know **everything** about you. That's why you are asked **every time** you start your app whether you want to share your screen.

Comment: only custom the dialog style means change the ugly layout to fit the theme of my APP right?

Comment: you said share screen is very serious yes I am totally agree I am not want to skip the confirm dialog. I wonder if I can make dialog myself and tell the system which button is deny or use the system deny button and agree button but the backgroundcolor or margin or text color I want to design by myself.

Comment: Yes, the Android confirmation window doesn't convince me graphically either and I also wish I could design it better. But as I wrote 8 hours ago: I've never heard of doing that. I think you can either change content **and** layout, or neither. But ask a new question on StackOverflow ("How to redesign the permission dialog window for capturing the screen?"), there are people here who have much more experience than I do.